# In Sympy, how do I define a generic function like f(x), such that sympy.diff(f(x), x) returns f' rather than 0.

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to take derivatives of this function

```
x, y, z, P, k, q = sp.symbols('x y z P k q')
expr = sp.exp(-sp.I*(P+k/(2*q)*(x**2 + y**2)))
```

where P and q are functions of z. How can I define P and q such that sp.diff(P, z) returns P' rather than 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you wrote, sympy can't know `P` and `q` are functions of `z`, can it? So it's treating them as constants - just like all the other variables except `z`. Your expression does not mention `z` at all, so it is all a constant expression - and the derivation of a constant is `0`, no exceptions.

Make sure `sympy` knows `P` and `q` are functions of `z`. And obviously, it matters what those functions are - you can't just leave them blank. A square differentiates differently than a square root. If you don't know, sympy will do the best it can:

```
x, y, z, k = sp.symbols('x y z k')
P = sp.Function('P')
q = sp.Function('q')
expr = sp.exp(-sp.I*(P(z)+k/(2*q(z))*(x**2 + y**2)))
sp.diff(expr, z)
# => -I*(-k*(x**2 + y**2)*Derivative(q(z), z)/(2*q(z)**2) + Derivative(P(z), z))*
#    exp(-I*(k*(x**2 + y**2)/(2*q(z)) + P(z)))
```

but if you do know, it can calculate it exactly:

```
x, y, z, k = sp.symbols('x y z k')
P = sp.Lambda(z, z * z)
q = sp.Lambda(z, sp.sqrt(z))
expr = sp.exp(-sp.I*(P(z)+k/(2*q(z))*(x**2 + y**2)))
sp.diff(expr, z)
# => -I*(-k*(x**2 + y**2)/(4*z**(3/2)) + 2*z)*
#    exp(-I*(k*(x**2 + y**2)/(2*sqrt(z)) + z**2))
```

Similarly, I don't think you can differentiate `P`, but this works:

```
sp.diff(P(z), z)
# => 2*z
```

Comment: If you `solve(sp.diff(expr, z), Derivative(P(z), z)` you will get `[k*(x**2 + y**2)*Derivative(q(z), z)/(2*q(z)**2)]`...and that is the result that `idiff` gives without having to explicitly create functions for `p` and `q`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `idiff` to get a fragile result with unevaluated derivatives: `dPdz = idiff(expr, (P, q), z)`. It is fragile in the sense that `dPdz.doit()` will give 0 because there is no explicit dependence on z for q.

```
>>> idiff(expr,(P,q),z)
k*(x**2 + y**2)*Derivative(q, z)/(2*q**2)
>>> _.doit()
0
```